# When tampering an assembly, why can't I remove original instructions?

Tags: mono, il, mono.cecil, tampering, ilspy

In order to be able to [test legacy code which relies on SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/151289/40736), I need to mock some of the objects of SharePoint. I do this by tampering with SharePoint assemblies, replacing *their* methods by mine on the fly.

This works for some cases, but not for others. A strange situation I encountered is this one.

I want to replace the getter of `SPContext.Current` by my own implementation; for the sake of simplicity, my implementation just throws an exception:

```
.property class Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext Current()
{
  .get class Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext Proxy.SPContextProxy::get_Current()
}

.method public hidebysig specialname static 
  class Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext get_Current () cil managed 
{
  // Method begins at RVA 0x877e68
  // Code size 12 (0xc)
  .maxstack 8

  IL_0000: nop
  IL_0001: ldstr "Proxy don't have an effective implementation of this property."
  IL_0006: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.NotImplementedException::.ctor(string)
  IL_000b: throw
} // end of method SPContextProxy::get_Current
```

When tampering the original assembly, if I **replace** the IL code corresponding to `SPContext.Current` getter, the property cannot be used any longer. I can't even visualize its contents in ILSpy, because this is what is shown instead:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadExceptionHandlers(Int32 count, Func`1 read_entry, Func`1 read_length)
   at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadSection()
   at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadFatMethod()
   at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadMethodBody()
   at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadMethodBody(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition.<get_Body>b__2(MethodDefinition method, MetadataReader reader)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Read[TItem,TRet](TRet& variable, TItem item, Func`3 read)
   at Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition.get_Body()
   at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Disassembler.ReflectionDisassembler.DisassembleMethodInternal(MethodDefinition method)
   at ICSharpCode.ILSpy.ILLanguage.DecompileProperty(PropertyDefinition property, ITextOutput output, DecompilationOptions options)
   at ICSharpCode.ILSpy.TextView.DecompilerTextView.DecompileNodes(DecompilationContext context, ITextOutput textOutput)
   at ICSharpCode.ILSpy.TextView.DecompilerTextView.<>c__DisplayClass16.<DecompileAsync>b__15()
```

On the other hand, when I **insert** my instructions before the original instructions, I can call the getter successfully, as well as see its contents in ILSpy:

```
.property class Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext Current()
{
  .custom instance void [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime]Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientCallableAttribute::.ctor() = (
    01 00 00 00
  )
  .get class Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext::get_Current()
}

.method public hidebysig specialname static 
  class Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext get_Current () cil managed 
{
  // Method begins at RVA 0x33e2d8
  // Code size 61 (0x3d)
  .maxstack 1
  .locals init (
    [0] class Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext,
    [1] class [System.Web]System.Web.HttpContext,
    [2] class Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext
  )
```

... follows by the instructions that I inserted:

```
  IL_0000: nop
  IL_0001: ldstr "Proxy doesn't implement this property yet."
  IL_0006: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.NotImplementedException::.ctor(string)
  IL_000b: throw
```

... follows by the original instructions:

```
  IL_000c: ldnull
  IL_000d: stloc.0
  IL_000e: call class [System.Web]System.Web.HttpContext [System.Web]System.Web.HttpContext::get_Current()
  IL_0013: stloc.1
  IL_0014: ldloc.1
  IL_0015: brfalse.s IL_0039
  .try
  {
    IL_0017: ldloc.1
    IL_0018: call class Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl::GetContextWeb(class [System.Web]System.Web.HttpContext)
    IL_001d: brtrue.s IL_0023

    IL_001f: ldnull
    IL_0020: stloc.2
    IL_0021: leave.s IL_003b

    IL_0023: leave.s IL_002a
  } // end .try
  catch [mscorlib]System.InvalidOperationException
  {
    IL_0025: pop
    IL_0026: ldnull
    IL_0027: stloc.2
    IL_0028: leave.s IL_003b
  } // end handler
  .try
  {
    IL_002a: ldloc.1
    IL_002b: call class Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext::GetContext(class [System.Web]System.Web.HttpContext)
    IL_0030: stloc.0
    IL_0031: leave.s IL_0039
  } // end .try
  catch [mscorlib]System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  {
    IL_0033: pop
    IL_0034: leave.s IL_0039
  } // end handler
  catch [mscorlib]System.InvalidOperationException
  {
    IL_0036: pop
    IL_0037: leave.s IL_0039
  } // end handler

  IL_0039: ldloc.0
  IL_003a: ret

  IL_003b: ldloc.2
  IL_003c: ret
} // end of method SPContext::get_Current
```

What prevents the code from being loaded by ILSpy when original instructions are removed before new ones are inserted?

**Notes:**

- Tampering is done with Mono.Cecil by using `MethodDefinition.Body.Instructions` collection (and the corresponding `Insert` and `Remove` methods.)
- A few other methods and properties of `Microsoft.SharePoint` assembly are tampered successfully: ILSpy displays the resulting IL code.
- I thought that `.maxstack` directive could be a problem (1 in the original property, 8 in the proxied one, 1 in the result). After a few tests on a separate project, it appears that it has no effect.
- I also suspected that exceptions could be the cause (the original code throws different exceptions than the new one). After a few tests [on a separate project](http://source.pelicandd.com/codebase/tampering/playground/MergeWithExceptions/), it appears that it has no effect either.

Comment: What does PEVerify say about the modified assembly? Is it possible that you removed original instructions, but not the corresponding exception handling clauses (`MethodDefinition.Body.ExceptionHandlers`)?

Comment: A diff of PEVerify results showed an additional error: *[...] SPContext::get_Current][offset 0x00000000] try end > code size*, thus, your guess is right. After replacing exceptions handlers, the problem was solved. Could you promote your comment to an answer, eventually explaining why in [this example](http://source.pelicandd.com/codebase/tampering/playground/MergeWithExceptions/), ILSpy doesn't complain, although the exception exists in the original method, but not in the proxy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When IL is shown in textual form, exception handling blocks (`.try`, `catch`, etc.) appear as actual blocks of IL instructions, just like they do in C#.

But in the binary form, exception handling blocks are stored separately (see [§II.25.4.6 *Exception handling clauses* of ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf#page=312&zoom=auto,87,221)) and reference the IL instructions using offsets. In Cecil, exception handlers are represented using the `MethodBody.ExceptionHandlers` property.

So, if you replaced the old `MethodBody.Instructions` with your own instructions, it's very likely that the offsets of the old exception handlers are now invalid, which is causing the issues. (The fact that Cecil throws `NullReferenceException` sounds like a bug to me, consider reporting it.)

The other example that you linked to which doesn't exhibit this problem is different because there the original method doesn't contain exception handlers, it *throws* an exception. And `throw` is just a normal IL instruction, it doesn't have a special representation like e.g. `.try`/`catch` does.